# Override url error: global name 'url' is not defined

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm tyring to override the url to call specific methods for different types of urls. Code below

Resources.py

```
class LCUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = LCUser.objects.all()
        resource_name= 'lcuser'
        authorization = Authorization()

def override_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r'^register/'%
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('register_user'), name="api_register_user"),
    ]
```

urls.py

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(LCUserResource())

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
]
```

I'm trying to access the api via  http://localhost:8000/api/v1/lcuser/register/

But i'm getting the error global name urls is not defined.

I tried importing 
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

Then I get No module named defaults

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import url

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting a not all arguments formatted error. I'm using Django 1.8 with tastypie 0.12.2 I'm wondering if my syntax is wrong on my resources.py override url

Answer (score 2):

The `django.conf.urls.default` was removed in django 1.6 as stated in the [depreciation notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-6):

> django.conf.urls.defaults will be removed. The functions include(),
>   patterns() and url() plus handler404, handler500, are now available
>   through django.conf.urls.

So, it seems like the documentation for `tastypie` hasn't been updated for django 1.8; you can fix the import error by fixing your import as mentioned in the release note:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

This will solve one issue - your next problem is here:

```
r'^register/'% (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash())
```

Not sure you what you are trying to do here as you are parsing a string (with `%`) but there are no variables to substitute. It is the same problem as this:

```
>>> a = 'world'
>>> 'hello' % (a,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

You probably want the following:

```
r"^register/(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash())
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the url to ` url(r"^register/", self.wrap_view('register_user'), name="api_register_user"),` and am trying to call it via `curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"cellphone": "cell", "password": "pass", "email": "email"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/lcuser/register/` But I get the error HTTP/1.0 501 NOT IMPLEMENTED

Comment: My bad. The url was wrong it should have been `url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/register%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('register_user'), name="api_register_user"),`

Comment: This is  getting out of topic but how do I access request Data? request.data['email'] returns an error